# Lift exists if induced cohomology maps satisfy the following properties

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X,Y,Z$ be CW complexes, and let $f : X \rightarrow Z$ and $g : Y\rightarrow Z$ be continuous. Let $H^\bullet$ be ordinary singular cohomology with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients.

Let $j_0 \geq 0$ an integer, and suppose:

- for every integer $k\geq 0$ with $k\neq j_0$, the induced morphism $H^kg : H^kZ\rightarrow H^kY$ is an isomorphism; and
- the induced morphisms $H^{j_0}g : H^{j_0}Z \rightarrow H^{j_0}Y$ and $H^{j_0}f : H^{j_0}Z \rightarrow H^{j_0}X$ are both zero maps.

Then does there exist continuous $h : X\rightarrow Y$ with $g \circ h = f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=Y=pt$ and $Z=S^1$, where $f\colon X\to Z:pt\mapsto 1$ and $g\colon Y\to Z:pt\mapsto -1$. Then, all the conditions are satisfied, where $j_0=1$.

However, there is no $h\colon X\to Y$ such that $g\circ h=f$.